# Get last top level command as a character string

Tags: r

Is there a way to get the last top level command stored into a character string without saving the history to a file and reading it back in just to grab the last command?  I have code for that

```
lastcmd <- function(){
    tmp <- tempfile()
    savehistory(tmp)

    # If we call this function then that call will
    # be the last line in the history so we want the one
    # before that
    tail(readLines(tmp), 2)[1]
}
```

and this isn't too bad but I was wondering if there was a way to get the history as characters without first writing to a file.

Comment: Have a look at `get("original", env = environment(history))`. I'd say except for a missing `unlink`, you are in pretty good shape.

Comment: @flodel That gives me an error.  Good point about unlink though.

Comment: @flodel -- Where is "original" documented? I copypasted your line and got the error msg that "original" is not found.  What should we be searching for?

Comment: In my version of R at home (the latest?), the code for `history` is hidden in a function named `original` and located in the environment of the `history` function. If `get("original", env = environment(history))` does not work for you, maybe you have a different version than mine. You could just try `history`. The whole idea was to show that `history` is already implemented in a similar manner to what Dason has above.

Comment: @flodel I can get the code with `get('history')` , but `??original` returns no such functions -R3.0.1 .

Comment: @flodel Just typing `history` for me shows me the code.  I did do that before posting but thought that the write out to a file might be partially because of the way that history shows the file with `file.show`

Comment: @flodel: Are you using RStudio? I'm getting different results depending on if I'm in RStudio or in an R terminal.

Comment: @flodel That is not the case for me (Rgui 3.1.1 on Windows).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a good use-case for a task callback. Basically, you can register a callback that will store the last top-level expression in a variable, which you can then subsequently access.

```
.lastcall <- NULL # create an empty variable to store into
# register your callback
addTaskCallback(function(expr,value,ok,visible) {
    assign(".lastcall", as.character(substitute(expr))[2], .GlobalEnv)
    TRUE},
    name='storelast')
# storelast 
#         1 

# check the callback on a bunch of things
2+2
# [1] 4
.lastcall
# [1] "2 + 2"
1:4
# [1] 1 2 3 4
.lastcall
# [1] "1:4"
matrix(1:4, nrow=2)
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    3
# [2,]    2    4
.lastcall
# [1] "matrix(1:4, nrow = 2)"
a <- 2; b <- 3
.lastcall
# [1] "b <- 3"

# cleanup everything; check that everything is cleaned up
removeTaskCallback('storelast')
# [1] TRUE
2+2
# [1] 4
.lastcall # confirm 2+2 was not stored as .lastcall
# [1] ".lastcall"
rm(.lastcall)
.lastcall
# Error: object '.lastcall' not found
```

You could also write the callback function so that it simply adds the last call to a vector (or a list or whatever) so that you build a full command history:

```
.lastcall <- character() # create an empty variable to store into

# register your callback
addTaskCallback(function(expr,value,ok,visible) {
    assign(".lastcall", 
           append(.lastcall, as.character(substitute(expr))[2]),
           .GlobalEnv)
    TRUE},
    name='storelast')
# storelast 
#         1 

# check the callback on a bunch of things
2+2
# [1] 4
.lastcall
# [1] "addTaskCallback(function(expr, value, ok, visible) {\n    assign(\".lastcall\", append(.lastcall, as.character(substitute(expr))[2]), .GlobalEnv)\n    TRUE\n}, name = \"storelast\")"
# [2] "2 + 2"                                                                                                                                                                                
1:4
# [1] 1 2 3 4
.lastcall
# [1] "addTaskCallback(function(expr, value, ok, visible) {\n    assign(\".lastcall\", append(.lastcall, as.character(substitute(expr))[2]), .GlobalEnv)\n    TRUE\n}, name = \"storelast\")"
# [2] "2 + 2"                                                                                                                                                                                
# [3] ".lastcall"                                                                                                                                                                            
# [4] "1:4"                                                                                                                                                                                  
matrix(1:4, nrow=2)
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    3
# [2,]    2    4
.lastcall
# [1] "addTaskCallback(function(expr, value, ok, visible) {\n    assign(\".lastcall\", append(.lastcall, as.character(substitute(expr))[2]), .GlobalEnv)\n    TRUE\n}, name = \"storelast\")"
# [2] "2 + 2"                                                                                                                                                                                
# [3] ".lastcall"                                                                                                                                                                            
# [4] "1:4"                                                                                                                                                                                  
# [5] ".lastcall"                                                                                                                                                                            
# [6] "matrix(1:4, nrow = 2)"                                                                                                                                                                
a <- 2; b <- 3
.lastcall
# [1] "addTaskCallback(function(expr, value, ok, visible) {\n    assign(\".lastcall\", append(.lastcall, as.character(substitute(expr))[2]), .GlobalEnv)\n    TRUE\n}, name = \"storelast\")"
# [2] "2 + 2"                                                                                                                                                                                
# [3] ".lastcall"                                                                                                                                                                            
# [4] "1:4"                                                                                                                                                                                  
# [5] ".lastcall"                                                                                                                                                                            
# [6] "matrix(1:4, nrow = 2)"                                                                                                                                                                
# [7] ".lastcall"                                                                                                                                                                            
# [8] "a <- 2"                                                                                                                                                                               
# [9] "b <- 3"                                                                                                                                                                               

# cleanup everything; check that everything is cleaned up
removeTaskCallback('storelast')
# [1] TRUE
2+2
# [1] 4
.lastcall # confirm 2+2 was not added to .lastcall
#  [1] "addTaskCallback(function(expr, value, ok, visible) {\n    assign(\".lastcall\", append(.lastcall, as.character(substitute(expr))[2]), .GlobalEnv)\n    TRUE\n}, name = \"storelast\")"
#  [2] "2 + 2"                                                                                                                                                                                
#  [3] ".lastcall"                                                                                                                                                                            
#  [4] "1:4"                                                                                                                                                                                  
#  [5] ".lastcall"                                                                                                                                                                            
#  [6] "matrix(1:4, nrow = 2)"                                                                                                                                                                
#  [7] ".lastcall"                                                                                                                                                                            
#  [8] "a <- 2"                                                                                                                                                                               
#  [9] "b <- 3"                                                                                                                                                                               
# [10] ".lastcall"                                                                                                                                                                            
rm(.lastcall)
.lastcall
# Error: object '.lastcall' not found
```

Remember with task callbacks, though, that it's really important that you cleanup after yourself with `removeTaskCallback` (or you can write the callback function to remove itself after some condition is satisfied; see `?addTaskCallback` for an example of that) otherwise `.lastcall` will linger around in your environment forever and keep being updated unnecessarily.

Comment: I really like this solution.  The only possible drawback being that you have to run this code before you get the ability to see the last command.  But I think will work out better than the solution I had for the problem I had in mind.  Thanks!

Comment: I also like this answer. Perhaps it would be of interest to note that if the command throws an error, it won't trigger the callback and won't get recorded in `.lastcall`.

Comment: @BenBarnes Good point. You could additionally write a custom error handler function that would update the `.lastcall` value so that you could record both successful calls and those that error out.

Comment: Another solution is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30552847/r-last-call-feature-similar-to-last-value).

Answer (score -1):

```
lastcmd <- function(){
   tmp<-tempfile()
   savehistory(tmp)
   readLines(tmp)[length(readLines(tmp))-1]
}
```

**Do u think it is better?**

Comment: No - it is not better.