# R .Last.call feature - similar to .Last.value

Tags: r

Similarly to `.Last.value` is there any way to access last call? Below expected results of potential `.Last.call`.

```
sum(1, 2)
# [1] 3
str(.Last.call)
#  language sum(1, 2)
```

The bests if it would not require to parse file from file system.

Comment: [Literally the first hit on Google when I typed "r last call"](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/last.call/docs/last.call)

Comment: So post it as an answer

Comment: @MikeWise I think their point is that the OP should've made an effort to source the answer instead of this being the first stop.

Comment: I actually cannot find the package last.call. Does it still exist?

Comment: Seems to have been removed: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/last.call/index.html

Comment: @ssdecontrol looking it at source of `last.call` package it looks similar to *.Rhistory* file and processing it. Reading last call from file on file system is not exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Have you seen this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18972845/get-last-top-level-command-as-a-character-string I know it's not exactly what you're looking for...

Answer (score 3):

The `last.call` package is no longer on cran, but you can still get the code:

```
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------
# FUNCTION: last.call
#   Retrieves a CALL from the history and returns an unevaluated 
#   call.
#
#   There are two uses for such abilities.  
#   - To be able to recall the previous commands, like pressing the up key
#     on the terminal.
#   - The ability to get the line that called the function.
#   
#   TODO:
#   - does not handle commands seperated by ';'
#
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------

last.call <-
function(n=1) {

 f1 <- tempfile()
 try( savehistory(f1), silent=TRUE ) 
 try( rawhist <- readLines(f1), silent=TRUE )
 unlink(f1)

 if( exists('rawhist') ) { 

   # LOOK BACK max(n)+ LINES UNTIL YOU HAVE n COMMANDS 
   cmds <- expression() 
   n.lines <- max(abs(n)) 
   while( length(cmds) < max(abs(n)) ) { 
      lines <- tail( rawhist, n=n.lines )
      try( cmds <- parse( text=lines ), silent=TRUE ) 
      n.lines <- n.lines + 1 
      if( n.lines > length(rawhist) ) break 
   }
   ret <- rev(cmds)[n] 
   if( length(ret) == 1 ) return(ret[[1]]) else return(ret) 

 }

 return(NULL)

}
```

Now, to use it:

```
sum(1, 2)
# [1] 3
last.call(2)
# sum(1, 2)
```

Comment: I was playing with it too just now :). Doesn't work if you "source" the code, everything counts as one line.

Answer (score 1):

I've modified this code to output text strings of the preceding commands / calls in a manner that preserves how there were formatted across lines in the original call, sot that I can use `cat()` to output the calls (for a function that emails me when the preceding function is done running). Here's the code:

```
lastCall <- function(num.call = 1) {
    history.file <- tempfile()
    try(savehistory(history.file), silent = TRUE ) 
    try(raw.history <- readLines(history.file), silent = TRUE )
    unlink(history.file)
    if (exists('raw.history') ) { 
        # LOOK BACK max(n)+ LINES UNTIL YOU HAVE n COMMANDS 
        commands <- expression() 
        num.line <- max(abs(num.call) + 1) 
        while (length(commands) < max(abs(num.call) + 1)) { 
            lines <- tail(raw.history, n = num.line)
            try(commands <- parse(text = lines), silent = TRUE) 
            num.line <- num.line + 1 
            if (num.line > length(raw.history)) break 
        }
        ret <- rev(commands)[num.call + 1]
        if (length(ret) == 1) {
            a <- ret[1]
        } else {
            a <- ret
        }
        # a <- rev(commands)[num.call + 1]
        out <- lapply(a, deparse) %>% 
            sapply(paste, sep = "\n", collapse = "\n")
    }
    out
}
```

Enjoy!

Comment: To answer your comment to the other post, if `'raw.history'` doesn't exist `out` will not be created and your code will fail. Original code returns `NULL` in that case.

Comment: Actually I think my advice on how to get character output wasn't that great, as here we are using both `parse` and `deparse`, so better not use `parse` in the first place and you'll have characters all along.

Comment: I would say it is best to avoid character at all and return just language object, a most recent call.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper, I think the initial `try(commands <- parse(text = lines)` is necessary to test whether the return string is a fully executable call and not just the last line of a multi-line call. But it might be possible to replace `ret <- rev(commands)[num.call + 1]` with  `ret <- rev(lines)[num.call + 1]` to avoid using `deparse`.

Comment: @jangorecki Josh wants characters to car, but I would personally keep the original function and use `sapply` / `deparse` on the output, or i'd add a parameter to choose the output format.